# regex to capture pattern with non-fixed length lookbehind - split string

Tags: r, regex

I'd like to split the string into the following

```
S <- "No. Ok (whatever). If you must. Please try to be careful (shakes head)."

[1] No.
[2] Ok (whatever). If you must. 
[3] Please try to be careful (shakes head).
```

The pattern is the first `.` before each `(...)`.

I'm familiar with `(?<=...)` (i.e. positive lookbehind) but this doesn't seem to work with non-fixed length patterns. I'd like to know if I'm wrong about positive lookbehind or if there's some regex magic to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how best to explain it then. I'm looking to split `S` by periods (`.`) that come before open parenthesis (`(`). For instance, the period after `No` is the first to occur (looking behind) from the `(` after `Ok`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that I don't know much about ruby, but there should be something like a `split` method that uses a regex pattern as a delimiter and split the string accordingly.

Use this regex:

```
(?<=\.) (?=[^.]+?\(.+?\))
```

This looks for a space character. Behind the space, there must be a dot `(?<=\.)`. After it `(?=`, there must be a bunch of characters that are not dots `[^.]+?`, and then a pair of brackets with something inside `\(.+?\)`.

Try it online: https://regex101.com/r/8PcbFJ/1

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! The use of `[^.]+?` is extremely instructive.

Comment: For other SO users, in `R`, `strsplit(S, "(?<=\\.) (?=[^.]+?\\(.+?\\))", perl=TRUE)` gives the intended result